# Fogged up window panes

Tags: windows

My large window in the living room has fogged up.  The contractor who flipped the house is not around. The window is 5 years old . Who will or is there a warranty? I I think he purchased them at lowes.

Comment: The warranty question is going to be up to the manufacturer. This then becomes product specific and legal advice, both of which are off topic here.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail. When does it fog? When it's cold outside and warm inside? After a shower? Is it single or double-pane glass? Is the fog inside or outside? Or between the panes?

Comment: Take a picture to Lowes.  Far more detail is needed, and effort, to make this a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The fog, if it's inside the window, means the air seal has broken. It will still work as a window, but likely isn't quite as energy efficient as it once was and the fog doesn't look great.

Flips, sadly, are typically done with less-than-top-of-the-line products. I'd say 5 year is a good run for something installed during a flip. You will likely have to just bite the bullet and replace the window at some point.

As for warranty, you'll have to find out what brand of window it is and deal with the manufacturer. Does it state on the outside anywhere? If not, bring in a local contractor who knows windows and they may be able to recognize it or, if not, can do some light demo work to get to the label that might be buried in the wall.

Answer (score 0):

A thermal window restoration company can come out, drill two holes, flush the inside of a fogged window, and install a permanent plastic vent.  But flipper windows from Lowes might not be worth saving.